# conversion from db2 to oracle

Tags: oracle, db2

```
SELECT MESSAGE_ID, SHORTDESC
FROM   VERNACULAR_MASTER
WHERE  position( chr(10), SHORTDESC, CODEUNITS16)>0
or     position( chr(13),SHORTDESC, CODEUNITS16)>0
```

The above query is in db2 format. How to convert it into oracle format?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to DB2's [`POSITION( search_string, source_string, encoding )`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023195.html) function is Oracle's [`INSTR( string, sub_string )`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm) function:

```
SELECT MESSAGE_ID, SHORTDESC
FROM   VERNACULAR_MASTER
WHERE  INSTR( SHORTDESC, CHR(10) )>0
OR     INSTR( SHORTDESC, CHR(13) )>0
```